# PHP Get Name of Associative Array from Key Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I'm storing in a Session variable as follows:

```
[availableCountries] => Array
        (
            [Australia] => 1031
            [New Zealand] => 1027
            [USA] => 1029
            [Singapore] => 1026
            [Canada] => 1028
            [France] => 1030
        )
```

I have a variable that stores a selected key value, e.g.:

```
 $country = '1026';
```

I now need to get the name of the matching Country from the array, e.g. Singapore where `$country = '1026'`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Comment: It's not clear how `"LP1026"` relates to `1026`. Is the value stored in `$country` always prefixed with `"LP"` or is that prefix dynamic?

Comment: @Phil sorry that was a mistake, have edited it to remove the LP as it should just be "1026" as the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're lookin for is [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search), that provides the functionality you're looking for:

```
$key = array_search(str_replace("LP", "", $country), $yourArray);
```

Which returns: `Singapore`

If you're looking for a quick and dirty way to return the data (*not recommended*), then you could even do this:

```
echo array_flip($a)[str_replace("LP", "", $country)];
```

<sup>*Provided the data is always present*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search() function.  It will search an array for a value and and return the key.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
$availableCountries = Array(

  'Australia' => 1031,
  'New Zealand' => 1027,
  'USA' => 1029,
  'Singapore' => 1026,
  'Canada' => 1028,
  'France' => 1030

);

function getCountry($array, $code){

  return array_search($code, $array);

}


echo getCountry($availableCountries, '1026'); //<---returns "Singapore"
```